# Correcting flowtype module.name_mapper path

Tags: flowtype

I am unable to get the proper regex working to map

`import immutable from 'npm:immutable'` to `import immutable from 'immutable'`

Anyone have a good suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
# Map imports named npm:<package> to <package>
module.name_mapper='^npm:\(.*\)$' -> '\1'
```

The `\1` represents everything caught in the first capture group `\(.*\)` so in your case that would be `immutable`